# What is the structure of "dorm room door"? Is it genitive?

Tags: possessives

I wonder where we can make genitive without 's or of. I know that using "of" in "dorm room door" might be complicated but the question is when we are allowed to make such phrases. 
[image]

Comment: Expressions such as _bathroom door, saucepan lid, bottle top_ are perfectly standard.

Comment: It's not a genitive. In texts the boundaries are sometimes clear, sometimes not, for instance:  ( (dorm room) (door) ) ...  ( (hotel) (room key) ) or  ( (hotel room) (key) ) although in speech the intonation/prosody would indicate the boundary. The speaker might say hotel-room key or hotel room-key.

Comment: Is there any rule for using this form or we are allowed to use it whenever we want instead of using "...  Of...."

Comment: There will always be exceptions but there's a very good chance that any combination you could dream up would be idiomatic, if the nouns refer to tangible things.  Garage window.    Candy wrapper.   Car tire.   Bicycle pump.  Salad fork.  Rain hat.  Nose ring.   Gate latch.  Park bench.

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer so you can write it as an answer for confirmation.

Comment: This question is frequently asked so I won't bother to add a duplicate answer.

Comment: It's just "Frankie's" that is genitive. "Dorm room door" is the NP that "Frankie's" determines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swan in *Practical English Usage*  has an entry called *noun + noun: advanced points*. In the *parts* section (p360) he states:

> We use the *'s* structure to talk about parts of people's and animals'
> bodies.
>
> - a man's leg -- an elephant's trunk -- a sheep's heart.
>
> But to talk about parts of non-living things, we usually use the *noun + noun*
> structure.
>
> - a table leg (NOT <strike>a table's leg</strike>)
> - a car door (NOT USUALLY <strike>a car's door</strike>)

This is not a hard-and-fast rule, as indicated by the *not usually* in the last example. Nevertheless, it is a useful guideline for English language learners.

Comment: Very interesting point. This is related to noun animacy, according to this paper: https://ac.els-cdn.com/S002438410700023X/1-s2.0-S002438410700023X-main.pdf?_tid=9a7cbfd7-6ded-456d-a870-4acde5e03826&acdnat=1553077091_fcd8c2842fd113fa87544eb3424152dc

Comment: "Leg" and "door" are inherent parts of "table" and "car", and hence are complements.